# How to utilize enums in this project?

Tags: java, enums

I've been looking at tutorials and articles about enums all morning and I'm just trying to wrap my head around how they can help me.

Here's my current problem:

I am making a program that helps manage items a player collects in a video game. The amount of space a player has is limited. Each character has only 88 slots. Items the player collects vary in size.

There are nine types of items:

> Boots (always size 4)
>
> Belt (always size 2)
>
> Helm (always size 4)
>
> Ring (always size 1)
>
> Amulet (always size 1)
>
> Gloves (always size 4)
>
> Body Armor (always size 6)
>
> Weapon (can be between sizes 2 and 8)
>
> Shield (can be between sizes 4 and 8)

To determine the size of a given weapon or shield, there is a table with all the different names and sizes. For example, the name Kite Shield corresponds to a size of 6. All this data is in a HashTable, the name being the key and the amount of space it takes up being the value. Just imagine this table is already somewhere in my program. The HashTable takes in a String name (ex. "Long Bow" and the value that corresponds to is 8) and returns an Integer size value.

```
public class Item
{
    /** Name is the first part of the item. Ex. Long Bow */
    private String name;

    /**
     * Defines what an item object is.
     * @param name of item.
     */
    public Item(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getItemSize()
    {
        // TODO: Algorithm here using Enums to determine size of a given item.
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here is the enum I made for the types of items, but I just can't see how this can be helpful.

```
// This is where I need help ↓
public enum types
{
    HELM, AMULET, WEAPON, BODY_ARMOR, SHIELD, RING, GLOVES, BELT, BOOTS;

    // How do I use this enum to help me determine size?
}
```

How can I use enums here to avoid using Strings and String.equals()? Thank you!

Comment: you told that Item size is stored in a hashtable, why do you need this values in the enum?

Comment: You said you have a hashtable with <name:size> pair. So why do require an enum?

Comment: The HashTable is only for weapons and shields, because they vary in size. I figure since all other seven types of items are constant in how much size they take up, why even use strings at all? Why not use enums. But I don't see how enums can help.

Comment: this design smells...

Comment: the next day you decide to create a legendary shield that has weight of 16 and that's how you get problems

Comment: @AdamSkywalker the game is Diablo 2 which came out in 2000, so the items and their sizes are pretty set in stone. If this is bad way of approaching it in that case, let me know!

Comment: Use enum only as an item type, store all artifact info in hashtable (sort of database). You can store default size value in enum (for boos or rings), but do not use this SHIELD_8 or SHIELD_4 enum values - it's clearly a bad design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store size items in your Enum. 
For items like Weapon and shield you already have HashMap so we'll just leave it blank in enum.

If the value of size is 0, which will be the case with WEAPON, we use HashMap.

```
public enum ItemType {
    HELM(4),
    AMULET(1),
    WEAPON(),
    BODY_ARMOR(6);

    private int itemSize;

    ItemType() {

    }

    ItemType(int itemSize) {
        this.itemSize = itemSize;
    }

    public int getItemSize() {
        return itemSize;
    }
}
```

Now, you can implement it like this in your Item class.

```
public class Item
{
    /** Name is the first part of the item. Ex. Long Bow */
    private String name;

    private ItemType type;
    /**
     * Defines what an item object is.
     * @param name of item.
     */
    public Item(ItemType type, String name)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getItemSize()
    {
        int size = type.getItemSize();
        if (size == 0)
            size = Constants.HASH_MAP.get(name);
        return size;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public ItemType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Create your Item class like this

```
Item longBow = new Item(ItemType.WEAPON, "Long Bow");
```

Comment: `size = Constants.HASH_MAP.get(name);` This is exactly what I couldn't grasp. Thank you -- this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

Enums in Java are just syntatic sugar to a class with several `final` properties with instances of the same class.

That being said, you cannot have variable items in an enum, which means your `weapon` and `shield` types will need some adaptation.

Here is what I've got for you:

```
enum ItemType {
    BOOTS (4),
    BELT(2),
    HELM(4),
    RING(1),
    AMULET(1),
    GLOVES(4),
    BODY_ARMOUR(6),
    WEAPON_2(2),
    //... other ones here
    WEAPON_8(8),
    SHIELD_4(4),
    //... other ones here
    SHIELD_8(8);

    private int size;

    ItemType(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

The only detail is that you should spread your weapon through `WEAPON_2`, `WEAPON_3`, and so on in order to be able to represent it within an enum. Same goes for `shield`.

Here is a [running example](https://ideone.com/un8xBa).

In order to integrate it to your game, let's suppose your `Item` class is as follows:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private ItemType type;

    public Item(String name, ItemType type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // getters and setters and anything else...
}
```

Then you instantiate it like:

```
Item sword = new Item("Excalibur", ItemType.WEAPON_4);
Item shield = new Item("Dragon Shield", ItemType.SHIELD_8);
```

Comment: Really cool. But now to apply it to my program. Every "Item" object in my program needs to have a "Type" variable. This type needs to be one of the ones listed in the enum. How would I do this? I can't really have an eum variable, can I? There's no such thing as `Constant type = BOOTS;` Ya know? So would I just have the Type as a String... and then.... I don't know actually. I still don't see how Enums can help me in this.

Comment: The thing I'm not getting is, how is this any better than the alternative here: https://ideone.com/GvNzdn (ignore the compile errors, obviously I didn't put any data in the HashTable).

Comment: @Hatefiend It's better to use strongly typed variable names in this case. You can make error or typo entering string data but it won't be the case with Enum values.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you can do is assign a `types` (BTW, I suggest a better name, like `ItemType`) to your `Item`s.

```
public class Item {
    private final ItemType myType;
    private final String name;
    private final int size;

    public Item(ItemType myType, String name, int size) {
        this.myType = myType;
        this.name = name;
        if ((myType.getMinSize() > size) ||
                (myType.getMaxSize() < size)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // or something else, whatever you want
        }
        this.size = size;
    }

    // various getters and other important stuff
}
```

You need to keep the `name` field because there is more than one `Item` of each `ItemType` and they have different `name`s (as well as sizes and, presumably, other properties).

Each individual `Item` must carry its own size, since they can vary. And that size belongs on the `Item` class since it's a property of the actual `Item`. But you could put a minimum and maximum on the enum, just for sanity checking.

```
public enum ItemType {
    HELM(4, 4), AMULET(1, 1), WEAPON(2, 8), BODY_ARMOR(6, 6), SHIELD(4, 8), RING(1, 1), GLOVES(4, 4), BELT(2, 2), BOOTS(4, 4);

    private final int minSize;
    private final int maxSize;

    public ItemType(int minSize, int maxSize) {
        this.minSize = minSize;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public int getMinSize() {
        return minSize;
    }

    public int getMaxSize() {
        return maxSize;
    }
```

Other uses will likely present themselves as you go, but just to be able to check `ItemType` against a set of known values rather than doing string checking is a win.
    }

Comment: I really like this idea. But at some point in my program, I am going to need to call myItem.getSize() and sure, if it is not a weapon or shield, it will return the value no problem. When it IS a `weapon` or a `shield`, it needs to take the name of the item (string) and pair it with the corresponding size (integer) from a `hashtable`. So... where would that be? Inside of the enum.. or does that not make any sense. Keep in mind I know almost nothing about enums besides the fact that it holds constant values.

Comment: Definitely not in the enum as I've presented it. At some point you know enough about the size of the `Item` to create the `HashTable`, right? So better would be to pass the size to the `Item` in its constructor and do away with the `HashTable` entirely. Will edit to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this class is more usable having min/max values.  It is not clear how you intend to use Types that can have a variable size.

```
public enum Types {

HELM(4, 4),
AMULET(1, 1), 
WEAPON(2, 8), 
BODY_ARMOR(6, 6), 
SHIELD(4, 8), 
RING(1, 1), 
GLOVES(4, 4), 
BELT(2, 2), 
BOOTS(4, 4);

private final int minSize;
private final int maxSize;
private Types(int minSize, int maxSize) {
    this.minSize = minSize;
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}

public int getMinSize() {
    return minSize;
}
public int getMaxSize() {
    return maxSize;
}
```

}

Then use Types.WEAPON.getMinSize() -or- Types.WEAPON.getMaxSize() accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I like enums. They save deveolpers a lot of unneccessary work. Instead of doing this:

```
class Foo{
    public static final Foo BAR1 = new Foo(4);
    public static final Foo BAR2 = new Foo(24);
    private Foo(int i){
        ...
    }
}
```

Developers can do this:

```
enum Foo{
    BAR1(4), BAR2(24);
    private Foo(int i){
        ...
    }
}
```

With a bunch of useful methods like `values()`, `valueOf()`, etc.

With your case, if an item can be either one size of between two sizes, I'd create a `minSize` and a `maxSize` in the constructor.

```
public enum WeaponType{
    BOOTS(4, 4),
    BELT(2, 2),
    HELM(4, 4),
    RING(1, 1),
    AMULET(1, 1),
    GLOVES(4, 4),
    BODY_ARMOR(6, 6),
    WEAPON(2, 8),
    SHIELD(4, 8);
    private int minSize, maxSize;
    private Weapon(int minSize, int maxSize){
        this.minSize=minSize;
        this.maxSize=maxSize;
    }
    public int getMinSize(){
        return minSize;
    }
    public int getMaxSize(){
        return maxSize;
    }
}
```

I don't know your exact case and needs, but about either minSize and maxSize or just size with a lot of WEAPON_ and a lot of SHIELD_, it would be a matter of preference. You can do whatever you think is better for your specific case.

Now your `Item` class can contain a `WeaponType` variable:

```
WeaponType wp;
```

And then with your getSize method in the item:

```
public int getSize(){
    int min = wp.getMinimumSize();
    int max = wp.getMaximumSize();
    //Do whatever with those
}
```